# What was the deal with Jeffrey Roston in "Body of Evidence" (1993)?

Tags: plot-explanation, body-of-evidence

As far as I understood, in the movie *Body of Evidence* (1993), Rebecca Carlson was getting help from Dr. Alan Payly to find rich people with heart diseases. She was establishing sexual relations with them, and manipulating them into writing their wills so that she would inherit money after their deaths.

The case against Rebecca was a managed one where the counselor, Frank, and public prosecutor, Robert, were both helping Rebecca, and hence, Rebecca won the case.

My question is, what was the deal with Jeffrey Roston? Did Rebecca really see him in bed with another man? I guess not?

Why did Jeffrey Roston nod his head and leave the courtroom? What was his weakness with regard to Rebecca?